# Definindo o construtor de um Objeto

Tags: java, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Olá, estou fazendo exercícios sobre construtores em Java mas estou com uma dúvida.

Tenho duas classes

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Duck[] d = new Duck[5];
        d[0] = new Duck();
        d[1] = new Duck();
        d[2] = new Duck();
        d[3] = new Duck();
        d[4] = new Duck();
    }
}
```

**Duck.java**

```
public class Duck {

    private int amountOfDucks;

    public Duck() {

        amountOfDucks++;

        if(amountOfDucks >= 1 && amountOfDucks <= 3) {

            System.out.println("Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!");
        }
        else if (amountOfDucks >= 4 && amountOfDucks <= 6) {

            System.out.println("Ha alguns patos na lagoa. " +
                "Quack! Quack!");
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Ha muitos patos na lagoa!! " +
                "Quack! Quack! Quack! Quack...");
        }

        System.out.println("Quantidade de Patos: "
            + amountOfDucks + "\n");
    }
}
```

Tenho a saída

> Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!
>   Quantidade de Patos: 1
>
> Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!
>   Quantidade de Patos: 1
>
> Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!
>   Quantidade de Patos: 1
>
> Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!
>   Quantidade de Patos: 1
>
> Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!
>   Quantidade de Patos: 1

Como faço para ter uma saída com o número de patos `amountOfDucks` crescente e não apenas 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o problema é que a sua variável `amountOfDucks` está codificada de forma que cada objeto tenha sua cópia dessa variável. Cada instância tem uma versão diferente e seus valores próprios. Então cada vez que você cria um novo objeto `Duck` ele vai ter o valor inicial que é `1`.

Pra esse valor ser compartilhado por todas instâncias você tem que declarar o campo como `static`. Ou seja, deve criar a classe como:

```
public class Duck {

    private static int amountOfDucks = 0;

    public Duck() {

        amountOfDucks++;

        if(amountOfDucks >= 1 && amountOfDucks <= 3) {

            System.out.println("Ha poucos patos na lagoa. Quack!");
        }
        else if (amountOfDucks >= 4 && amountOfDucks <= 6) {

            System.out.println("Ha alguns patos na lagoa. " +
                "Quack! Quack!");
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Ha muitos patos na lagoa!! " +
                "Quack! Quack! Quack! Quack...");
        }

        System.out.println("Quantidade de Patos: "
            + amountOfDucks + "\n");
    }
}
```

Aí sim, quando você referencia `amountOfDucks` a partir de qualquer instância você obtem a mesma coisa, porque ao declarar como `static` o campo passa a ser compartilhado, ou seja, ele é algo *da classe* e não *dos objetos*.

Uma última observação: se o campo fosse público você poderia referenciar a partir de outras classes. Nesse caso, você referencia usando o nome da classe antes do ponto, ou seja, teria que usar `Duck.AmoutOfDucks`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!